# get file size of an url from text file that contain urls

Tags: php, url, size, filesize

i want an php script or software to determine file size of URLs placed in a text file
this script have to read each line of text file (each line is a url) and determine file size and finaly calculate the total size of whole urls
in simple :
input : 
site.com/lst.txt (list of urls)
output:
size of files // example 5.2G

this is a code i found that can calculate **single** url file size if possible edit this for me to what i mentioned above :

```
<?php
/**
 *  Get the file size of any remote resource (using get_headers()), 
 *  either in bytes or - default - as human-readable formatted string.
 *
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @license MIT <http://eyecatchup.mit-license.org/>
 *  @url     <https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/f26300ffd7e50a92bc4d>
 *
 *  @param   string   $url          Takes the remote object's URL.
 *  @param   boolean  $formatSize   Whether to return size in bytes or formatted.
 *  @return  string                 Returns human-readable formatted size
 *                                  or size in bytes (default: formatted).
 *
 *  <code>
 *  //example
 *  echo getRemoteFilesize('https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/archive/master.zip');
 *  </code>
 */
function getRemoteFilesize($url, $formatSize = true)
{
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;
    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!$formatSize) {
        return $clen; // return size in bytes
    }
    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }
    return $size; // return formatted size
}
$url = 'url_here';
echo getRemoteFilesize($url); // echoes "7.51 MiB"
```

thanks

Comment: Do you mean the size of downloaded data from those URLs ?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: yes i want size of downloading file from urls -

Comment: i found a code that determine size of single url but it is not what i want . i want to calculate size of all urls that saved in txt file in each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a `HEAD`-request to all of the URLs and sum the `Content-Length` header for each of them.

Using the code you provided:

```
function getRemoteFilesize($url)
{
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;
    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }
    return $clen; // return size in bytes
}

function formatBytes($clen) {
    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }
    return $size; // return formatted size
}

$urls = array('http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com');

$sum = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < count($urls); $i++) { 
    $res = getRemoteFilesize($urls[$i]);
    if ($res != -1) {
        $sum += $res;
    } else {
        echo 'content-length could not be retrieved for ' . $urls[$i];
    }
}

echo formatBytes($sum);
```

Comment: thanks its working . i change the code to what i need and send the result

Answer (score 0):

that code mentioned above is working nice but in order to use text file as input and each line of it as array we can equal `$urls` to text file with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to make each url as input